# What is the difference between lxd and lxc

Tags: lxd

I want to work with lxc containers.
I have installed ubuntu lxd package, but i work with lxc command.
So i do not understand what are the differences between lxc and lxd containers.
Is it the same thing ?

Comment: LXD is like LXC wrapper. https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/introduction/

Comment: thanks. Is that true that docker works with LXC ?

Comment: Not any more, docker dropped lxc for their own solution two years ago I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LXD is a daemon service that exposes REST API and manages the containers via liblxc.

LXC is a command line tool that calls REST API locally or remotely.

https://www.mywebtech.blog/guide-linux-lxd-containers-ubuntu/